# How to counting sort two dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, counting-sort

Hi i have a problem with my code, i try sort array by counting sort (it must be stable sort), but my code doesn't work. I try implemented counting-sort from some wbesite, but it was in c# and I'm not sure s it done correctly. Can you tell me what is wrong with it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void sort_with_show(int **a, int rozmiar, int polecenie)
{
    int y, d;
    for (int i = 0; i< rozmiar - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rozmiar - 1 - i; j++)
        {
            if (a[j + 1][0] < a[j][0])
            {
                y = a[j][0];
                a[j][0] = a[j + 1][0];
                a[j + 1][0] = y;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rozmiar; i++)
    {
    //cout << tablica[i].x << " " << tablica[i].y << "\n";
        if (polecenie == 0)
        {
            cout << a[i][0] << '\n';
        }
        else if (polecenie == 1)
        {
            cout << a[i][0] << "," << a[i][1] << "\n";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{


    int rozmiar = 0;
    int polecenie = 0;

    char t[20] = { '\0' };
    char *p, *q;

    int liczba = 0;
    int calaLiczba = 0;

    bool isY = false;
    cin >> rozmiar;

    int ** a  = new int *[rozmiar];
    for (int i = 0; i < rozmiar; i++)
        a[i] = new int[2];

    cin.ignore();

    int i = 0;
    while(i < rozmiar)
    {
        fgets(t, sizeof t, stdin);

        for (p = t, q = t + sizeof t; p < q; p++)
        {

            if (*p >= 48 && *p <= 57)
            {
                liczba = *p - 48;
                calaLiczba = calaLiczba * 10 + liczba;
            }

            if (*p == ' ')
            {
                a[i][0] = calaLiczba;
                isY = true;
                calaLiczba = 0;
                liczba = 0;
            }

            if (*p == '\n')
            {
                a[i][1] = calaLiczba;
                isY = false;
            }

        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            t[j] = '\0';

        liczba = 0;
        calaLiczba = 0;
        isY = false;
        i++;
    }

    cin >> polecenie;
    cin.ignore();

    sort_with_show(a, rozmiar, polecenie);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You need to be more specific. What is wrong? Does it compile? Does it crash? Does it give wrong answer? Give some input/output examples, etc. and limit the code sample to minimum.

Comment: In your function, how does the compiler know the quantity of rows and columns in your array?  The matrix could be 5x5, 1x3 or 256x16384, and your function won't know.  Array dimensions are not passed to your function.  In order to use `[][]` notation, the compiler needs to know the number of columns. You have passed a pointer to a pointer to a single integer.  Use `std::vector` to resolve or use a matrix class.

Comment: I can't use STL library, compiler show me a exception:
Exception in 0x000D6335 w Sortowanie liniowe.exe: 0xC0000005: Violation of access policies while reading in a location 0xA6E82D4C.

Comment: Array should have "rozmiar" rows and 2 columns